# Ubuntu Server Manager Installation Fails on 13.04 - Why

Tags: gnome, server, dependencies

Installation of Server Manager Utility on 13.04 fails.  Have tried many combination of loading  packages to fix.  Dependency Problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-server.  Denpendency on on gir1.2-launchpad-integration-3.0 is not installed (but I installed it)  Process fails when Processing Triggers for gnome-menus.  Fails on both GNOME and KDE desktops.  Any ideas out there ?

Answer (score 0):

There are some dependecy peoblems with Ubuntu 13.04 , because you need more than gir1.2-launchpad-integration-3.0 , install the app using gdebi and check out the dependency errors and try to install those manual ( just search on google the dependecy you need , doenload and install'it ) ....I shoud get back with anoter post to tell you exacly what dependecy you need!
Cheersz!

Comment: Found 'it ...just download and install in this order accordind to your architercture the following dependency:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/liblaunchpad-integration-common

http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/liblaunchpad-integration-3.0-1

http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/gir1.2-launchpad-integration-3.0